# how to look back on rows until criteria matched

Tags: libreoffice, formulas, libreoffice-calc

Consider the following sheet example:

```
  A1 A2

1 5  10
2 6  12
3 -3 9
4 1  10
5 5  15
6 -4 11
7 9  20
```

How do I look back from row 6 and sum all A2 rows until a previous negative A1 row.
In this example: 15 + 10 = 25

Comment: this is no question for `SO` (no programming involved). try `SuperUser` instead.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without programming involved!

Comment: You can do it with a formula (I think so, your problem description is vague): Use a helper column to `SUM` column `B` if `A` on row above is not negative; start with `0` if otherwise . Your tagging "formulas" suggests you are looking for one. 
If you want a programming solution: show your effort with some code (what language would you use?), what errors you encounter, where is "the problem".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `-3` is in A3, in C4 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(A3<0,0,C3+B3)
```

This creates a running total, starting immediately after the first negative in the left hand column, that resets after each negative in the left hand column.